# VB.NET Performing XOR On Decimal Values

Tags: vb.net, xor

I'm porting some code from php to vb.net, but I stuck
on the XOR function. I cannot perform the XOR when one of the
values is greater than integer datatype range.

Here is my testing code :

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim A As Integer = 1254378503
    Dim B As Integer = 3058210502 'Overflow here
    Dim SIGN1 = A Xor B
    Dim SIGN2 = EncodeBase64(SIGN1)
    MsgBox(SIGN2)
End Sub
Public Function EncodeBase64(ByVal input As String) As String
    Return System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
End Function
End Class
```

I've been browsing through other posts regarding my question, but honestly
I cannot find any solution or simply cannot understand it. The basic question is how do I perform XOR on decimal datatype (greater then integer) just like php does.

Any help or hint on how to achieve it will be much apreciated.

Comment: If you need even larger numbers than what `Long` or `Decimal` allows, have a look at [**`BigInteger`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx). It supports XOR as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer. Use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Basically, the `Integer` type is too small to hold the values you are using in your sample.

The output of your test code is `NDIzNzA4OTQ3Mw==` - coded through VS Express, just to show that this actually works.